# Display custom option on category list page in magento

Tags: magento

I want to display **product custom options** on products list page, and when i add to cart it will go to cart page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mugur, Sorry if above link is missing, you can use bellow code

```
$productSku = $_product->getSku();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productId = $product->getIdBySku( $productSku );

$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);

$attVal = $product->getOptions();

$optStr = "";

// loop through the options
foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal) {

  //$optStr .= "";

  //$optStr .= $optionVal->getTitle().": ";

  $optStr .= "<select style="display: block; clear: both;" name="options[&quot;.$optionVal->getId().&quot;]">";

  foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
    $optStr .= "<option value="&quot;.$valuesVal->getId().&quot;">".$valuesVal->getTitle()."</option>";
  }

 $optStr .= "</select>";

}

 echo($optStr);
```

Comment: This is wrong and taken from another question here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4480/custom-options-in-product-list/4499. Clearly it's not a good way to do it. Check answer from Vinai on this page.

Comment: From performance point of view its bad to completely reload the product in product list.

Answer (score 2):

found the solution here finally. If anyone need to do the same, it can be done using a code in the theme list.phtml file. Checck the code here: http://blog.sparxitprofessionals.com/display-custom-option-on-category-list-page-in-magento/

Comment: where in the list.phtml do you add that code? I pasted it before the buy now button and it is invalid.

Comment: Link is not available anymore. Please find a way to paste the code here if available.

Answer (score 0):

- Reloading the product by `->load()` is not idea from performance point of view
- A bit better is to get the options by:

  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product)
- But the best solution would be to join the custom options to the product collection. If anyone has a solution for this feel free to post it here :)